# In Objective-C, how to read the contents of several files packed inside a ZIP archive, into an NSString variable

Tags: objective-c, zip, zlib, compression

In Objective-C (for iOS), is there any way to read the files inside a ZIP archive into memory?

So, each file inside the ZIP is a text file. And what I need to do is to iterate through the files inside the ZIP archive until I locate the one I need by name, and then to read its contents (which is text data) to an NSString variable.

Is this possible to do with zlib? I can't see in the header of this library anything to perform such a task, as reading files inside a zip archive.

Also other libraries i checked on the interent seem to decompress to a directory only, but, what I need is to read the contents of the files inside the zip archive into an NSString variable only.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly quickly using my [zipzap](http://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap) library:

```
ZZArchive* archive = [ZZArchive archiveWithContentsOfURL:zipFileURL];
NSString* foundContent = nil;
for (ZZArchiveEntry* entry in archive.entries)
  if ([entry.fileName isEqualToString:fileNameToFind])
    foundContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:entry.data
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries out there you can use.  Google is your friend.  [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/), [libarchive](http://www.libarchive.org/) are just two.